# How do I index through an array I've read from a .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm just starting with Python - but have over 60 years experience in other programming languages, which may be part of the problem. Clearly there's something fundamental about Python that I don't seem to be getting.

Using Numpy and Pandas. I just read in a 2 x 4 CSV file. Now I want to iterate through the array modifying the first column of every row. I checked the size with size=np.shape(InputArray)

when I try to access the 1st element of "size" with n=size(0) I get an error 'tuple" object is not callable

Similarly if I try to access the input array by indexing into it ie x=InputArray(1,m)
. Clearly I'm missing something very basic here.

By the way, the 2 x 4 array is just a test. The actual array I need to process is vastly bigger

Thanks much ie x=InputArray(0,1)

Comment: To get the first element of `size` you need `size[0]`. In python you use square brackets for indexing. Parenthesis are used for calling functions.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` bracket is used to access element of an array in python. But here you are using `()`, that's why you are getting error as **'tuple' object is not collable**.
To access 1st element of array named size, you should use `size[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. I think I finally found the solution to the problem I was having accessing the actual array (the suggested answer worked for "Size" but not to index the array proper.) I found that instead of trying to index (for example) ABC, the variable into which I read the file I have to access it as ABC.iloc(index1, index 2) which I think is how I pass the indices to what is effectively a function (iloc) that maps the indices to the physical structure of the actual object.

My experience was with ancient languages like Fortran and PL/1 as well as machine language - not to mention plugboard wiring. It was a long time ago. Things have changed.